# Lattice xyplot - Matrix used to divide groups into subplots

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a lattice xyplot with a group argument. There are 5 different values for the variable used to group and the plot is divided into a 2x3 matrix with an empty box in the upper right corner. However, I would like to divide the plot into a 1x5 matrix instead. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
   xyplot(prop ~ indtegn_alder | salgskanal,
   data=fewGrid2,type='smooth',span=0.20, lwd=2.5,
   xlab="Alder", ylab="Sandsynlighed", ylim=c(0,0.5), group= first_kundetype)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `layout=` parameter on the `?xyplot` help page.It allows you to specify the number of columns and rows you would like

```
xyplot(prop ~ indtegn_alder | salgskanal,
data=fewGrid2,type='smooth',span=0.20, lwd=2.5,
xlab="Alder", ylab="Sandsynlighed", ylim=c(0,0.5), group= first_kundetype,
layout=c(1,5))
```